# Unordered_map, check for threshold in a sliding window

Tags: c++

I have an unordered_map, the keys represent the minutes in an hour (from 0 to 60) and the value the number of event at that minute.

What I want is in a given window size is to check if the sum events is above some threshold.

for instance, let's say I have this unordered_map=`[(4,3),(5,2),(7,2)]`
window size = 3 (minutes)
threshold = 6

so in this example I don't have a window of 3 minutes with more than 6 events, but if window size was = 4 then do.

What is the best way to approach this? I thought copying the unordered_map to a map because it's key sorted.

next I thought of having a sliding window that each time adding the new element and dropping  the oldest, but I'm having trouble doing it because minutes who don't have events don't show in the map (like minute 6)m how do I overcome this?
(I don't want to manually add the empty minutes like (6,0) because they are way too many, more than evented minutes)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's **the best** approach, but I would go with `map` instead of `unordered_map`, use iterators to load consecutive elements to a temporary `list` as long as they are within window and check their total events from there

```
std::map<int, int> map{ {4,3},{5,2},{7,2} };
std::list<std::pair<int, int>> list;
const int threshold = 6, window = 4;
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
{
    while (list.size() > 0 && it->first - list.front().first >= window)
        list.pop_front();
    list.push_back(*it);

    int count = 0;
    for (auto e : list)
        count += e.second;
    if (count > threshold)
        std::cout << "over threshold" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
```

Try it on [cloliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fdbc81d7bd11ae9)!

Comment: the check for list.pop_front should be while, not if, as more than one value can exit the window.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for your problem?

```
size_t cur_idx = 0;
array<size_t, 3> window;
auto LoadEventsPerMinute = [&] (size_t minute) {
  auto it = event_map.find(minute);
  window[cur_idx] = (it == event_map.end()) ? 0 : it->second;
  cur_idx = (cur_idx + 1) % window.size();
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < window.size() - 1; i++) {
  LoadEventsPerMinute(i);
}

for (size_t i = window.size() - 1; i < 60; i++) {
  LoadEventsPerMinute(i);
  size_t num_events = window[0] + window[1] + window[2];
  if (num_events > threshold) {
    // Do your thing
  }
}
```